# Angular2 post request despite a XMLHttRequest error

Tags: ajax, http, angular, xmlhttprequest, angular2-http

I send a request to a remote API. It takes a little time for API to proceed on its side.

After this little waiting time, i can see in network tab a HTTP 200. In the response, I got the proper intended information. Everything on the API side works fine.

BIT on the console, I can see I encountered a XMLHttpRequest Error.

**Why, especially if I have a XMLHttpRequest Error, the POST is completed with 200? Shouldn't it be "blocked" by Angular2?**

The unintended result is: **my file is correctly uploaded and handled by the API, but in Angular2, it triggers the ERROR part of my call**.

If I use https://resttesttest.com/ for example, it seems to encounter the same error but it doesn't finalize the POST:

> Oh no! Javascript returned an
>   HTTP 0 error. One common reason this might happen is that you
>   requested a cross-domain resource from a server that did not include
>   the appropriate CORS headers in the response.

Angular 2 Code for this call

```
this.http
    .post(this.documentUploadAPIUrl, formData, options)
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        this.responseData = res.json();
        console.log(this.responseData);
        console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Upload failed! Error:', error);
      }
    );
```

[image: Console]

Comment: You need to setup CORS on the server https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: first you should read the link by J J B second what you are using as backend to create the APIs

Comment: It's a JAVA backend i guess. Not my own work. The strange thing is i get an error on console even if the status is finally 200...

Comment: Can you post the headers of the first 2 requests that are content-type text/html?

Comment: Added on question the content of first request. Second is the same plus `Proxy-Authorization: NTLM lRMAAAAD01JQzcxMDVDR0lfUUM`. **The problem seems really to be the fact a XMLHttpRequest Error is triggered and it pass over the fact the status is 200**.

Comment: Do you thinks it's possible the problem is due to the fact Angular2 doesn't seem to send a OPTION request prior to POST request? If I create a basic Ajax request, it seems to send an option and be blocked at this point, without going through POST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to set withCredential attribute of xmlHttpRequest to true, this will send credentials managed by the browser, in angular 2 you can do like this

```
    import { RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';


    this.http
      .post(this.documentUploadAPIUrl, formData, this.post_options)
      .subscribe(
        res => {
         this.responseData = res.json();
         console.log(this.responseData);
         console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
        },
        error => {
         console.log('Upload failed! Error:', error);
        }
       );



post_options() {
   return new RequestOptions({ method: 'post', withCredentials : true  });
}
```

Comment: Tested it doesn't work. I reformated my question to be more precise. Angular2 in fact waits properly for call to be complete. The status is 200 but an error is thrown due to the cross-domain XMLHttpRequest and **Angular doesn't in fact see the status 200, it only catch the error**. I tried an upload call from localhost using postman, everything works.

Comment: Nope, already thought about it and it doesn't change anything.